# Avoid swift nested if let tests

Tags: swift

I am doing some swift with web services. I am using alamofire. The code is working but i think that it's not "readable" ( not a clean code). Do you have an idea how i can optimise this ? Thanks

```
static func checkBookValidity(serialNumber: String, callBack: Result<Bool?> -> ()) {

      let router = Router.CheckBookLuggage(serialNumber: serialNumber)
      let request = Alamofire.request(router)
      request.validate()
      request.response { (request, response, data, error) in
         if let error = error {
            if error.code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet {
               callBack(.Failure(.NoConnection))
            }
            else {
               if let data = data {
                  do
                  {
                     if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject] {
                        let erroType = WSError.errorTypeWithJson(json, httpErroCode: error.code)
                        callBack(.Failure(erroType))
                     }
                  } catch {
                     callBack(.Failure(.ServerError))
                  }
               }
               else {
                  callBack(.Failure(.ServerError))
               }
            }
         }
         else {
            if let data = data {
               do
               {
                  if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject] {
                     if let resultDic = json["result"] as? [String:AnyObject], let exists = resultDic["exists"] as? Bool {
                        if exists {
                           if let owner = resultDic["email"] as? String {
                              // ...
                           }
                        }
                        else {
                           callBack(.Success(false))
                        }
                     }
                  }
               } catch {
                  callBack(.Failure(.ServerError))

               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Take a look at the [`guard` statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID434) ;)

Comment: You should probably ask this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, i know the guard statement :). Do you have an idea if i can use the guard combing optional binding and calling functions that trow ? ( see my example when trying parsing the json and binding the "data")

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
if let error = error, data = data {
    do {
        if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject] {
            let erroType = WSError.errorTypeWithJson(json, httpErroCode: error.code)
            callBack(.Failure(erroType))
....
....
```

if let statements can be chained together with comma, as in `error` and `data` above.
The same can be done with guard.